# IA32 IDT and linux interrupt handler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, interrupt

In the IDT each line has some bits called "DPL" - Descriptor Privileg Level, 0 for kernel and 3 for normal users(maybe there are more levels). I don't understand 2 things:

1. this is the level required to run the interrupt handler code? or to the trigger the event that leads to it?. because system_call has DPL=3, so in user-mode we can do "int 0x80". but in linux only the kernel handle interrupts, so we can trigger the event but not handle it? even though we have the right CPL.
2. In linux only the kernel handle interrupts, but when an interrupt(or trap) happens, what get us into the kernel mode?

Sorry for any mistakes, I am new to all this stuff and just trying to learn.

Answer (score 4):

The IDT has 3 types of entries - trap gates, interrupt gates and task gates (which nobody uses). For trap gates and interrupt gates; the entry mostly describes the target CS and EIP of the interrupt handler.

The DPL field in an IDT entry determines the privilege level required to use the gate (or, to switch to the target CS and EIP described by the gate). Software can only use a gate via. a software interrupt (e.g. `int 0x80`).

For IRQs and exceptions hardware uses the gate and not software. Hardware has no privilege level and is always able to use a gate (regardless of which privilege level software is currently using and regardless of the gate's DPL). This means that IRQ handlers should have DPL=0 (to ensure that software running at CPL=3 can't use them via. software interrupts).

When an interrupt handler is started, the CPU determines if there will be a privilege level change or not (based on the privilege level that was in use beforehand and the target privilege level that's almost always zero) and automatically switches privilege level where necessary. This is what causes the switch to CPL=0. *Note: CPU will also switch stacks and save "return SS:ESP" on the new stack if a privilege level change was necessary.*

Comment: But system call has DPL=3, so the cpu doesn't need to change CPL, so why we change it?

Comment: Because one of purpose of the system call is to change the CPL.

Comment: @Josh: DPL is the privilege level you need to be able to use it. E.g. if an interrupt is set to "DPL=1" then code running at CPL=3 or CPL=2 can't use it (will get a general protection fault) and code running at CPL=1 or CPL=0 can use it. The new privilege level will be the same regardless of who used it. Note that "use the interrupt" means using a software interrupt (like `int 0x80`) - for IRQs and exceptions the CPU knows that hardware is using it and not the current software, so CPL isn't checked.